# Create insert script from query result

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

A few times a week, I need to create SQL insert scripts from query results in pgAdmin III.

Currently, I do this manually. Is there a function in pgAdmin to export a query result to an SQL Insert script ? I use a postgreSQL database.

Or is there another (open source) tool which can do this ? I'm running Ubuntu Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no feature as such in pgadmin refer [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1361699582.2245.13.camel%40localhost.localdomain). But you can use pg_dump.
First create a table to export the result to a table as follows.

```
create table ex_table as 
select id, col1, col2
from table
where col3 = 'value1'
```

Then pg_dump as follows,

```
$ pg_dump --table=ex_table --data-only --column-inserts my_database > data_with_inserts.sql
```

Another alternative is to use [this](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) SQL Workbench tool.